# SciFi show with alien invasion in form of big cloud that consumes everything

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I looking for a show in which earth is attacked by big cloud-like structure that groves/moves slowly and consumes everything on its path. I watched it about fifteen years ago. In one scene a jet (maybe F-16) tries to destroy it and flies into it. It surprisingly survives and flies through some sort of energy tunnel and exits the cloud. I'm not sure of this part but I think pilot heard voices of people consumed by cloud. The cloud had electric discharges in it. In other scene someone says that cloud is near some town and it ended that episode.

It was not animation. It was about fifteen years ago, in Poland, on a channel on 'Wizja TV' TV network. It was in English with Polish voice-over.

Comment: When did you see this show? In what country? On what TV network? In what language (subtitled, dubbed, or neither)? Any detail can help! :-)

Comment: It was about fifteen years ago, in Poland, on a channel on 'Wizja TV' TV network. It was in English with Polish voice-over.

Comment: Was the jet an RAF tornado?  if so I think I know what it is, just cannot remember exactly what it is called - googling

Comment: Was it Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like Invasion:Earth (BBC miniseries) & especially the scene from  the final episode: The Shatterer of Worlds

> Drake and Amanda fly into the structure to launch a missile directly
>   into the portal, in the hope of causing a chain-reaction that will
>   destroy it. The plan seems to work at first, and Drake's plane
>   successfully escapes from the collapsing nD structure, but the joy of
>   the Earth forces proves short-lived—within moments a new structure
>   rises up in place of the first, expanding at an even greater rate.
>   Amanda now realises that the plan has failed and that there are
>   probably an infinite number of other nD structures which can be
>   'folded down' into normal space to replace any that are destroyed

https://youtu.be/tiLR9CMtAQk?t=395

Comment: I need to watch entire show to be sure, but I think this is what I was looking for. The structure and the fly through it looks very similar to what I remember. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

This could be the 1988 The day the earth stood still.  In the end GORT a robot releases a cold of nanobots to consume everything.  Klato the being is able to stop them.